# How do i calculate this multivariable limit?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am really uncertain about how to approach this but here's my attempt:

Let $$x=(x_1,x_2,x_3), \; \mathopen|x\mathclose|=(x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}+x_3^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

If the following limits exist, find their value:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ln(1+\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2)}{\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2+sin(x_1x_2x_3)}$$

My attempt is simply to estimate an upper bound, and then using the standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{ln(1+x)}{x}=1$,

$$\frac{\mathopen|ln(1+\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2)\mathclose|}{\mathopen|\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2+sin(x_1x_2x_3)\mathclose|}\leq\frac{ln(1+\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2)}{\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2}$$
Because the $ln$ function with that input is positive, and the $sin$ function takes on a max value of $1$. But, $$\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2\rightarrow0 \;\text{when}\;x\rightarrow0$$ so $$\frac{ln(1+\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2)}{\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2}\rightarrow1$$

Comment: $||x|^2+\sin(x_1x_2x_3)|\geq |x|^2$ is not true. Moreover, are you sure that $|x|$ is not the square root of you you wrote ?

Comment: yes forgot to write that! I see now why the inequality does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use AM-GM inequality and $|\sin(t)|\leq|t|$ to bound $|\sin(x_{1}x_{2}x_{3})|$ in terms of $|x|$.

---

Here's a full solution: factor the equation into
$$
\frac{\ln(1+|x|^{2})}{|x|^{2}} \times \frac{|x|^{2}}{|x|^{2} + \sin(x_{1}x_{2}x_{3})}
$$
where the first part goes to 1 as $|x| \to 0$. For the second part, AM-GM inequality gives
$$
|x|^{2} = x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2} + x_{3}^{2} \geq 3 (x_{1}x_{2}x_{3})^{2/3}
$$
so we have
$$
|\sin(x_{1}x_{2}x_{3})| \leq |x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}| \leq \left(\frac{|x|^{2}}{3}\right)^{2/3} = \frac{|x|^{3}}{3^{2/3}} = O(|x|^{3}).
$$
Hence the second part also converges to 1 since
$$
\Bigg| \frac{|x|^{2} + \sin(x_{1}x_{2}x_{3})}{|x|^{2}} - 1\Bigg| = \frac{|\sin(x_{1}x_{2}x_{3})|}{|x|^{2}} \leq \frac{|x|}{3^{2/3}} \to 0.
$$
So the answer is 1.

Comment: Given your Hint, how do you upper-bound $\frac{1}{||x^2|+\sin(x_1x_2x_3)|}$ ?

Comment: becuase $\mathopen|x\mathclose|^2\geq \mathopen|sin(x_1x_2x_3)\mathclose|$ an upper bound is $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: what does the O mean?

Comment: why does the inequality after "so we have" hold? Should the exponent not be 3/2?

Answer (score 1):

Divide all the terms by $|x|^{2}$ and use the fact that $|\sin (x_1x_2x_3)| 
\leq |x_1x_2x_3| \leq \frac  1 2 |x_3| |x|^{2}$ (since $|x_1x_2| \leq \frac1 2 (x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}))$. Final answer : The limit is $\frac 1{1+0}=1$.

Comment: $\lim \frac {\log (1+|x|^{2})} {|x|^{2}}=1, \lim \frac { |\sin (x_1x_2x_3)} {|x|^{2}}=0$. As I said **you have to first divide all the terms by $|x|^{2}$ for my argument to work**. @Surb

Comment: is that because of the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: @edwindakwesi Yes, the inequality I wrote for $|x_1x_2|$ is AM-GM inequality.